# What type of wood should I use for my wood fence?

Tags: wood, fence

We have about 100 feet to cover. 
My neighbor and I are splitting the cost and we want the best value for the following characteristics:

1. Longevity/durability
2. Rot resistance
3. Termite resistance

We would consider a cheaper wood and add the cost of safely treating the wood to get those characteristics. (We have kids and pets and don't want chemicals fro the treatment to harm them)

Comment: If you want it to last forever and not require any maintenance, don't use wood, use synthetic.  There are versions that are similar to the resin/wood composites used for decking, and some that are entirely resin.  They will initially cost more than wood, but you never have to touch them again.

Comment: What environment is this for?  What part of the world?  The region affects materials costs.

Comment: Southern California - dry weather

Answer (score 1):

No natural wood that I know of will resist termites. Cedar lasts best in Texas. I think redwood may outlast cedar but is considerably more expensive, at least around here. My 6' tall privacy fence has galvanized steel posts, 2x4 pressure treated rails and cedar slats.

Comment: Redwood will outlast just about anything but is horribly expensive even here where it grows.

Comment: Is there anything that we can spray on the wood to help with durability and insect resistance?  Something not toxic...

Answer (score 0):

You might consider two type of wood. One type for the posts, another type for the panels.  For example, store bought pressure treated posts, and sawmill bought full dimension green stock for the panels.  The sawmill stock would be cheaper and the wood would be thicker than the store bought version. For example, from the sawmill, a 1x6 would measure something like 1" thick and 6" wide, where as from a store it would measure 3/4" by 5.5", or even thinner if you buy fencing lumber.  Thus the sawmill stock would not only be cheaper, but also have more wood.